# Pushing viewController which is not in tab controller without hiding the tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabcontroller

I have a tab controller in which five viewControllers are there. I even have a side menu bar which has the list of other viewControllers . My problem is when i try to click any list to move to viewController it get pushed over the screen, hiding the tab bar at the bottom. How can i show the tab bar at bottom for this scenario. I got some ideas but it dint helped.

Comment: *What* gets *"pushed over the screen"*? The "side menu bar"?

Comment: to push viewController listed in side menu

Comment: My guess is that what you need is a navigation controller between the tab bar controller and each of the child view controllers

Comment: OK - show the code that is being called when you select a line on your "side menu"... I'm assuming it is a list of the Tabs, and you want to jump to that Tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your tab bar controller is you root view controller.

1. Your story board should look like

   tabbarController -> NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2
2. Your VC1 to VC2 segue has to be a show segue, not a present modally because the second one makes V2 the root view controller.